# angular replace method not working on string

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a method that appends a string if a checkbox is checked, and if not checked, it should remove the value from the string using the `replace()` method

The code for the method:

```
current_search : string = "";
generateLink(e, n) {
    if(e.checked){
        this.current_search = this.current_search + " " + n + ",";
        console.log(this.current_search);
      } else {
        this.current_search.replace(n, '');
        console.log(this.current_search);
      }
}
```

Nothing gets updated on the string when the checkbox is unchecked. When it is checked, the string is appended with whatever 'n' is as that is being passed into the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually replace methods returns the new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement, what your doing is not saving the return value of replace method

```js
let a = "how ur doin";
a = a.replace('ur','');
console.log(a);
```

try by saving return value of replace method by
 `this.current_search = this.current_search.replace(n, '')`

Comment: thumbs up. but doesnt it clash with concept of two way data binding or the replace function creates a new object.?

Answer (score 1):

use bellow for angular 2+

```
_var.split("/").join("_")
```